# Unable to set RefNumber via QuickBooks XML (qbXML version 11.0)

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I've tried both CheckAdd and CheckMod, and have been unable to set the RefNumber using QuickBooks Pro 2012 on Windows XP. I searched for RefNumber in the QuickBooks SDK Concepts Manual and didn't see anything that might address this problem. On the web, I did see [a QODBC post](http://archive.qodbc.com/forum6bc8.html) on the topic.

Here's the CheckMod I tried. I don't receive an error when I issue this request; the RefNumber just isn't set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <CheckModRq>
            <CheckMod> <!-- required -->
                <TxnID >85-1388374219</TxnID> <!-- required -->
                <EditSequence >1388374219</EditSequence> <!-- required -->
                <RefNumber>12345678901</RefNumber>
            </CheckMod>
        </CheckModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: See my comments explaining why no answer has been yet accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is if the check is marked "To Be Printed" (or "Print Later" in later versions of QuickBooks), you'll need to mod this to false in order for the RefNum to save. I tested using the following request (my TxnID and EditSequence will of course be different):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "stopOnError">
        <CheckModRq requestID = "0">
            <CheckMod>
                <TxnID>3CF-1389105873</TxnID>
                <EditSequence>1389106557</EditSequence>
                <RefNumber>12345678901</RefNumber>
                <IsToBePrinted>0</IsToBePrinted>
            </CheckMod>
        </CheckModRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce my error, and haven't seen the To Be Printed text within the checks. Perhaps the latter caused the former. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I wasn't able to verify Hpjchobbes answer, though from time to time I did see "To Be Printed" in checks. My guess is that his/her answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, only using QBFC.  I fixed it by changing the line :

requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 2, 0)

To:

requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0)

So by referencing QBXMLMajorVersion that was older they changed something so it would stop saving the refnumber.  Changing it to the 13 fixed it.

Comment: Thanks; maybe someone else will be helped by your answer. I don't have version 12 or 13, so I can't verify your solution, sadly. I did try versions 2 through 10 with no success, though that's not what you were suggesting.